# Why is AdMob screwing with my basic music play/pause app when I haven't even tried using anything remotely linked with AdMob

Tags: admob, android-mediaplayer

I really don't understand why is Android giving me shit when i'm not even using AdMob.
All I'm trying to do is, add 2 buttons saying 'play' and 'pause' for the sole purpose of trying to understand how to use the MediaPlayer class and app keeps crashing with the following message:-

---

```
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************
```

I don't even have my AdMob configured.
I am sure my code is correct, but I'm unable to de-bug this, even after trying to follow what's written in the above mentioned links.

Following is my code:-

```
package com.arsh.android.musicplayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.musicfile);

        Button Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        Button Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all admob dependency if you are not using it and try again

Comment: I checked every bit of the code, including the gradle and the manifest files. There are no dependencies anywhere, and that's what's been confusing me, that why I'm getting an error for AdMob when they're no dependencies for the same in the code.